# Error when calling scikit-learn using AMD64 build of Scipy on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting this error on this line:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

The error log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\KaggleDigits\KaggleDigits.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .forest import RandomForestClassifier
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 47, in <module>
    from ..feature_selection.selector_mixin import SelectorMixin
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .univariate_selection import chi2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\univariate_selection.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 320, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 241, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 529, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After installing:

- Python 2.7.4 for Windows x86-64
- scipy-0.12.0.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe (from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))
- numpy-unoptimized-1.7.1.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe (from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))
- scikit-learn-0.13.1.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe (from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/))

Anybody know why this is happening and how to solve it ?

Comment: Ah I just missed the part where it said that you need the MKL statically linked version of Numpy ... fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please copy this comment as an answer to your own question and accept it? It will help mark this question as resolved.

Comment: I was hoping someone else would reply, so I could accept their answer, you cannot accept your own answer before 2 days.

Comment: No problem. Let's just wait for 2 days then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Christoph Gohlke mentioned on his download [page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), the scikit-learn downloadable from his website requires Numpy-MKL. Therefore I made a mistake by using Numpy-Unoptimized.

The link to his Numpy-MKL is statically linked to the Intel's MKL and therefore you do not need any additional download (no need to download Intel's MKL).

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but for those like me, download these from the official 
[Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

After that restart your interpreter/console and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me when I use scipy 0.12. After I changed to scipy 0.11, the problem was gone.