# Installing Scipy Error in Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, installation, windows-7-x64

In a round about way, I corrupted my scipy/numpy installation on my IntelX64/Windows 7/Python 2.7 computer.  I did this by trying to play around with some neural network libraries (lasagne/theano).

To fix this, I completely removed/reinstalled python 2.7.9.  After that, I went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  to download and install numpy and scipy with commands:

```
pip install C:\Users\me\Documents\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This went well and succeeded. (I can import numpy from python)

```
pip install C:\Users\me\Documents\scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This appeared to go well too. Except the error occurs in the python console:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 338, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 184, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 586, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I read up on the DLLs required and ran the 'dependency walker' (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special_UFUNCS.PYD" and it seems there are a few DLL files not found.

```
libifcoremd.dll
libiomp5md.dll
libmmd.dll
msvcr90.dll
dcomp.dll
ieshims.dll

and a 6 files that look like 'api-ms-win-....dll'
```

From my looking around, people have solved this by reinstalling numpy, then scipy.  I have tried that and the same thing occurs.

Has anyone else run into this issue and solved it?

Comment: That may be the cause.  I have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition installed.  The trial has expired.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by a complete removal of everything (python and packages) and then installing everything again.

Just reinstalling the offending packages did not work.  Neither did system restore. I will not accept this answer, because removing/installing is a work around to the real problem.  I just want to post this to help anyone else in this position.

Answer (score 3):

Simply install 'NumPy-1.9+MKL' from this [page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), it should work fine.

Acknowledgement: Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536881/error-when-calling-scikit-learn-using-amd64-build-of-scipy-on-windows) here :)